# Как создать песок в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно подробное описание механизма и принципов(например это делается с помощью системы частиц или нет?Или же технологии PhysX ?) создания и имитация песка в большом объеме, ветер который будет сдувать часть песка с возвышенностей. Идеально было бы как в игре Journey. Только прошу не пишите "ну это с помощью того - то или того то нужно делать" - мне нужны желательно не только принципы создания, но и конкретные примеры - ссылки на текстовые/видео туториалы.

Comment: Сюда смотрели? https://www.cnet.com/news/making-the-perfect-video-game-sand/ или например сюда? http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1017742/Sand-Rendering-in

Comment: @justyx избегайте [отсылок в гугл](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349)